# Ruby on Rails // Getting a Strange Return on .each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, erb

I am making a shopping cart for a web app.  So far it has 3 components: 'products', 'line_items' and 'carts'.  The flow seems to be okay.  I am getting all the returns I want.  But, after the .each loop, I am getting a return of the entire product model.

[image: What is showing when rendered in Chrome]

The code being rendered:

```
<hr>
<%= @cart.line_items.each do |line_item| %>
   <%# binding.pry %>
   Item: <%= line_item.product.name %><br>
   Price: <%= line_item.product.price %><br>
   Quantity: <%# line_item.quantity %><br>
   <hr>
<% end %>
<hr>
```

What I can't figure out is why this bit at the end is rendered.  When I run a `binding.pry` to inspect the '@cart' I can't find this final return.  It looks like it is returning the product models as an array.

I am not sure what other parts of the code that would be helpful.  It is currently up to date on [GitHub](https://github.com/a-White-Rabbit/flea_market) if you want to have a look.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `<% foo.each` in your views, not `<%= foo.each`.

The later executes the loop, and then outputs the return value of `foo.each`, which is `foo` (the collection itself).

> It looks like it is returning the product models as an array.

That is exactly what `for.each` does. Using `<%` will cause the return value to be silently discarded, while `<%=` outputs it to the browser.